# Problems with a makefile

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to compile this [program](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-38/openssl/fips-1.0/rand/) but when I try to execute the `make` command I get an error: (I'm using Ubuntu in Spanish)
[image: Screen Shot of MAKE error]
It says that it goes to directory /home, but then it says that "there is no rule to build the objective sub_all.  Stop.".  Then it exits the directory /home and finally stops, with the "[top] Error 2" shown.

Can anyone help point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add the code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download [the entire project](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-38/), not just the `rand` subdirectory.
The Makefile says:

```
# 
# OpenSSL/fips-1.0/rand/Makefile
#
```

So you will have:

```
/home/usuario/Desktop/OpenSSL-38/
```

and `rand` will then be at

```
/home/usuario/Desktop/OpenSSL-38/openssl/fips-1.0/rand/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! sorry for being late.

Comment: You're welcome! The time doesn't matter. As long as it helps you!